# fabricJS format image on iOS native code

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, image, fabricjs

I need to create FabricJS format image in iOS native application which can be edited(change background, rotate image etc) and saved on server in FabricJS format. The image from server can be retrieved again by any iOS and other platforms (android, web portal etc) and can be edited again.

My queries:
1. Is there any framework for iOS which can help me to create FabricJS type image?
2. is there any other cross platform approach apart from FabricJS which can be used to create object model for an image?

Comment: Hi SHN,
Have you found any solution for this. i am trying but solution not found.

Comment: Hi SHN,
Have you got any solution for above?